# How to reboot iPhone/iPod from mac or Xcode

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I want to restart an iPod Touch/ iPhone connected to mac mini without touching the device, Is there any way to reboot from Terminal or Xcode or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. No Public API to do so.

However, if your phone is jailbroken & OpenSSH is installed, you can connect to your phone via SSH, then type:

```
su
reboot
```

to reboot your phone.